About path-connected components of the Bohr compactification of $\mathbb{R}^d$
Let ${\rm b}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the Bohr compactification of $\mathbb{R}^d$, with $d\in\mathbb{N}$. This is the Pontryagin dual of the group $\mathbb{R}^d_d$, corresponding to $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the discrete topology. There exists an injective, continuous (but not bi-continuous) group homomorphism $\iota: \mathbb{R}^d \to {\rm b}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I would like to know whether it is known what the path-connected components of this space are. Particularly, I'm interested in knowing how many there are. Here's what I know:

${\rm b}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is connected, since $\mathbb{R}^d_d$ is torsion-free (Theorem 46 of [Pon])
${\rm b}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not path-connected, since $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{R}^d_d,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \prod_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}_d \neq \{0\}$ (Theorem 2 of [Dix])
$\iota(\mathbb{R}^d)\subset{\rm b}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is path-connected, and Theorem 1 of [Dix] leads me to believe it might be a path component.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

References:
[Pon] Pontryagin, L.S.: L. S. Pontryagin Selected Works: Topological groups. Volume 2
Gordon and Breach Science Publishers. Classics of Soviet mathematics, Montreux, 1986
[Dix]  Dixmier,  J.: Quelques propriétés des groupes abéliens localement compacts.
Bull. Sci. Math. (2)  81,  38-48 (1957)
